# how to lock input language in MS Word

Tags: ms-word, input-language

When i switch language between Thai and English i normal use a shortcut key **`**.

But the in word i have a document which need to all need to be written in Thai but the problem is when i click on different part of the document that has a number or a blank space it switches to English. So how do i make input language to lock to a specific language?

I also don't want to be going in to control panel to add and delete the language setting or keep changing language in region and setting.

Comment: Is this programming-related?

Comment: The problem is likely because your Word language default differs from your Windows language default. When that's the case, when a new document is created the Windows language overrides the Word language as "direct formatting", resulting in the behavior your describe. I wrote an article about this, many years ago. Follow the instructions in it and things should improve... http://homepage.swissonline.ch/cindymeister/LangFmt.htm

Comment: @CindyMeister thank you this does help me a lot